# How to differentiate between primary mailbox and archive mailbox in mapi while getting mailboxes using IExchangeManageStore::GetMailboxTable?

Tags: active-directory, exchange-server, archive, exchange-server-2010, mapi

I'm using mapi to retrieve information about mailboxes in my organization. When I use IExchangeManageStore::GetMailboxTable method, it returns both primary mailboxes and archive mailboxes. How do I differentiate between the two?

Answer (score 0):

You can't - primary and archive mailboxes are indistinguishable. If you open the mailboxes, you can check if default folders are set (archive mailboxes should have the same folders, but PR_IPM_CONTACT_ENTRYID etc. would not be set if fi remember correctly.

Why not simply get a list of Exchange users from GAL and look for the entries with PR_EMS_AB_HOME_MDB present?